# Tomb of annihilation party composition

Tags: tomb-of-annihilation

I'm a new DM who's going to run Tomb of Annihilation for a group of 4 players soon.

We are a new group and they will be creating new characters for the purpose of the adventure. Seeing as we are new and from my reading of the adventure it seems to be somewhat tough at times, I want to make sure we have a good time by making a good party composition, especially for the  challenges they will face during the adventure.

The players are as follows:

1. One player who's a little more experienced and will mostly choose his character to fit with the group. He has already created a tortle fighter. I can't remember which subclass, but we wanted him to be a tank so he went with a tanky one. Anyway, if needed he might change his character as it wasn't his first choice anyway.
2. Another player has insisted for a long time that he wants to play a ranger and have a panther companion. I think it might be a good idea for the adventure anyway, but he hasn't created his character yet so if you have any suggestion for a subclass we'll appreciate it.
3. The third player doesn't seem to care too much, and actually prefers me to build his character for him. He does seem to be interested in non-support magical classes, though.
4. The last player also doesn't have a specific idea. He seemed okay with the idea of support.

Of course I'm not asking you to do all of the work for us, but some general suggestions would be appreciated.

Sorry for the long(?) question and thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is just going to result in a bunch of list answers of what people think the optimal build for any party is, I think.

Comment: Hi Lambusy, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. It looks like you're asking us to recommend you class choices or a party composition, but we can't facilitate that. We're a Q&A site that focuses on questions that can have a single best or correct answer, whilst this would just result in an arbitrary list of ideas (as Theik points out). This is a discussion starter you could instead ask on a forum, [such as one of these we'd recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449).

Comment: I understand what you mean, I'll definitely check out a forum. Thanks!

Comment: @Lambusy Thanks for understanding. You're still welcome here whenever you have a problem or question that might fit the way we might work.